# i am facing issue with for loop in jQuery

Tags: jquery

[link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/h70qz8bs/)

i am facing problem with for loop in jQuery

i want to show value one by one

1 then 2 then 3 upto 50

but it showing 1 to 50 at the same time

html

```
<div><span></span></div>
```

js

```
var i=0;


for(i=0;i<=50;i++)
{
    $("div").hide().append("<span>" + i + "</span>" + "\n").fadeIn(500);

}
```

Comment: How do you actually want it to look? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Note that the for loop itself is just JavaScript. And actually the jQuery library is JavaScript too.

Comment: @DJ_Polly He wants to do it like a countdown. One number after the other, not altogether.

Comment: Try this http://fiddle.jshell.net/h70qz8bs/16/

Comment: thanks anoop this is what i want to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
for (i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
    $("div").append($("<span/>", {
        text: i
    }).hide().delay(i * 400).fadeIn(300));

}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/h70qz8bs/23/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this : instead of loop, you can use setInterval where append the count value and increment the count.

```
var i = 0;
var limit = 50;

var interval = setInterval(function () {
    $("div").append("<span>" + i + "</span>" + "\n").fadeIn(500);

    if (i == limit) clearInterval(interval); //stop interval
    i++;
}, 2000);
```

**[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/h70qz8bs/10/)**

Comment: All appended is dancing in `setInterval` time.. you should do best fit
and ever stop it mean `OP` want to show  `1-50`?

Comment: Also remove .hide() from your script. I think it will be much better. This will remove the so Called "dancing" by Girish... lolz

Comment: there is no limit of i.

Comment: @Yunus : [**yeah..this looks much better**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/h70qz8bs/15/) :)

Comment: I Updated my answer to remove dancing and to limit the count. thank you all for your inputs :)

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar thanks a lot but my question was for loop not for time interval

Comment: No problem .. I just suggested another way to achieve your goal without loop :)